# NodeRT: could not find assembly

Tags: node.js, windows-runtime, windows-10, electron

I am writing an [electron](https://github.com/electron/electron) app with [electron-windows-notifications](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-windows-notifications) which is dependant on [NodeRT](https://github.com/NodeRT/NodeRT).

As I try to install my project, I get following error for each of `@nodert-win10` dependencies:

```
> if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Applications\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --msvs_version=2015 )  else (node "" rebuild --msvs_version=2015 )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  _nodert_generated.cpp
  NodeRtUtils.cpp
  OpaqueWrapper.cpp
  CollectionsConverterUtils.cpp
..\_nodert_generated.cpp : fatal error C1107: could not find assembly 'Windows.winmd': please specify the assembly search path using /AI or by setting the LIBPATH environment variable [C:\Users\moro\projects\t w-en-ty\node_modules\@nodert-win10\windows.ui.startscreen\build\binding.vcxproj]
..\NodeRtUtils.cpp : fatal error C1107: could not find assembly 'Windows.winmd': please specify the assembly search path using /AI or by setting the LIBPATH environment variable [C:\Users\moro\projects\tw-en-t y\node_modules\@nodert-win10\windows.ui.startscreen\build\binding.vcxproj]
..\CollectionsConverterUtils.cpp : fatal error C1107: could not find assembly 'Windows.winmd': please specify the assembly search path using /AI or by setting the LIBPATH environment variable [C:\Users\moro\pr ojects\tw-en-ty\node_modules\@nodert-win10\windows.ui.startscreen\build\binding.vcxproj]
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
..\OpaqueWrapper.cpp : fatal error C1107: could not find assembly 'Windows.winmd': please specify the assembly search path using /AI or by setting the LIBPATH environment variable [C:\Users\moro\projects\tw-en -ty\node_modules\@nodert-win10\windows.ui.startscreen\build\binding.vcxproj]
C:\Applications\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\src\win_delay_load_hook.cc : fatal error C1107: could not find assembly 'Windows.winmd': please specify the assembly search path using /AI or by se tting the LIBPATH environment variable [C:\Users\moro\projects\tw-en-ty\node_modules\@nodert-win10\windows.ui.startscreen\build\binding.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Applications\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Applications\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Applications\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--msvs_version=2015"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\moro\projects\tw-en-ty\node_modules\@nodert-win10\windows.ui.startscreen
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Please, can you help me?

This question was also asked here: https://github.com/NodeRT/NodeRT/issues/56.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying full installation process on a different computer I found an issue causing this problem. In install instructions it is stated that **"VS 2015 Express for Windows Desktop"** is needed. However, Visual Studio itself is not enough and when installing a person has to install **Windows 10 SDK** as well.

Retrospectively it seems obvious but for someone new to JS-native-related technologies, it might be useful to explicitly declare this in README. :)

Answer (score 15):

I was also getting following error:

```
d:\nodejs\app\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\src\win_delay_load_hook.cc : fatal error C1107: could not find assembly 'Windows.winmd': please specify the assemb
ly search path using /AI or by setting the LIBPATH environment variable [D:\nodejs\work\app\node_modules\@nodert-win10-cu\windows.applicationmodel\b
uild\binding.vcxproj]
d:\nodejs\work\app\node_modules\@nodert-win10-cu\windows.applicationmodel\opaquewrapper.cpp : fatal error C1107: could not find assembly 'Windows.wi
nmd': please specify the assembly search path using /AI or by setting the LIBPATH environment variable [D:\nodejs\work\app\node_modules\@nodert-win1
0-cu\windows.applicationmodel\build\binding.vcxproj]
d:\nodejs\work\app\node_modules\@nodert-win10-cu\windows.applicationmodel\nodertutils.cpp : fatal error C1107: could not find assembly 'Windows.winm
d': please specify the assembly search path using /AI or by setting the LIBPATH environment variable [D:\nodejs\work\app\node_modules\@nodert-win10-
cu\windows.applicationmodel\build\binding.vcxproj]
d:\nodejs\work\app\node_modules\@nodert-win10-cu\windows.applicationmodel\_nodert_generated.cpp : fatal error C1107: could not find assembly 'Window
s.winmd': please specify the assembly search path using /AI or by setting the LIBPATH environment variable [D:\nodejs\work\app\node_modules\@nodert-
win10-cu\windows.applicationmodel\build\binding.vcxproj]
d:\nodejs\work\app\node_modules\@nodert-win10-cu\windows.applicationmodel\collectionsconverterutils.cpp : fatal error C1107: could not find assembly
 'Windows.winmd': please specify the assembly search path using /AI or by setting the LIBPATH environment variable [D:\nodejs\work\app\node_modules\
@nodert-win10-cu\windows.applicationmodel\build\binding.vcxproj]
```

I followed the following steps:

1. Create a folder(check building.gyp file for path)

   %ProgramFiles(x86)%/Microsoft Visual Studio
       14.0/VC/lib/store/references
2. Copy file `platform.winmd` from

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
       Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x86\store\references
3. Copy file `Windows.winmd` from

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
       Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17763.0

did the trick to fix the "platform.winmd", "Windows.winmd" error for me!

Comment: Nice answer!
A little extra info  -actually exact paths might change from version to version, so if it doesn't work,
open `binding.sln` in Visual Studio, and check Library Directories... Then copy the winmds to the correspondent path.

Comment: in step 3, it isn't clear what the copy destination is for the `windows.winmd` file.

Comment: in step 3. Copying the `windows.winmd` to the root of `UnionMetadata` worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else dealing with this issue. I fixed it by copying Windows.winmd

from

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.16299.0

to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata

Comment: This fixed my issue, however there's no explanation as to why this works. I first tried adding the appropriate folder to the PATH and LIBPATH environment variables like the error suggests, but that didn't work.

Comment: This hack didn't work for me -- see my answer below, I think it's more fool proof and probably 'the right way.'

Comment: In my case copying Windows.md alone from the applicable SDK folder did not work. I also had to change the path specified in "Additional #using Directories" path (on C/C++->General in Project Settings) from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\vcpackages" to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\Common7\IDE\VC\vcpackages" since my project was configured for VS2017 while I was building it under VS2019 Preview edition.

Answer (score 3):

You need to match your installation of the Windows 10 SDK exactly with the required version of NodeRT.

As recommended by some of the answers here, I installed various versions of the Windows 10 SDK and Visual Studio 2015 over the course of a few frustrating hours and still nothing.

Finally, after a bit of research and coming across the official NodeRT page:

https://github.com/NodeRT/NodeRT

I saw it lists exactly which Windows 10 SDK you need for each version of nodert.

Looking a bit closer at my exact error messages I saw it was complaining about nodert-win10-cu, so according to the above page I needed to install exactly the SDK Windows 10, Build 15063. After doing that it compiled like a charm, but only for that exact SDK version. Somehow of all the SDKs I installed, I did not install that exact one :).

I hope this helps someone else for whom the other answers didn't work. They get you close, but the details are important --  match your installation of the Windows 10 SDK exactly with the required version of NodeRT using the above link.

Comment: I think this is part of it. Also, I'm seeing that one may need VS2015 build tools installed since NodeRT is still not compatible with VS2017 (or likely VS2019) apparently: see https://github.com/NodeRT/NodeRT/issues/65 and/or https://github.com/NodeRT/NodeRT/issues/113#issuecomment-428306790

Comment: I found the exact name of it was: Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.468) and Microsoft Emulator for Windows 10 mobile (10.0.15254.1), and was able to download it here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=845298

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to get the entire process to work for windows.devices.geolocation with Electron.

1. Install Visual Studio 2017 with build tools and the platform SDK separately from the Microsoft site. I installed Windows 10 platform SDK ver 17134.
2. Get the latest source for NodeRT (3.0) and build it using Visual Studio 2017.
3. Run the built application. I used the NodeRTUI.exe file you can use the command line version as well.
4. Point Winmd file location to the folder where the platform SDK is installed. For me it was under C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17134.0\
5. Select Windows.Devices.Geolocation or whatever the RT module(s) you want
6. Select Visual Studio 2017, Windows 10 and the location of the output folder.
7. Click the "Generate and build module" and don't worry if you get an error message.
8. Navigate to the output folder where you generated the output files
9. run `node-gyp rebuild --msvs_version=2017`
10. If the build fails because the platform.winmd file cannot be located then do the following.
11. Search for platform.winmd file on in your ProgramFiles(x86). This should have been installed part of Visual Studio installation
12. Open the binding.gyp file from your NodeRT generated output project and locate the path for WIN_VER=="\v10\"" and copy the platform.winmd file to that location and copy the plaftform.winmd file to that location. For me it was `%ProgramFiles(x86)%/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/lib/store/references`
13. Now the build should work without any issues. Run the test.js file from the output folder to make sure everything is working.
14. To use this node addon in Electron, it needs to be rebuilt to match the exact version of Electron you are using. (otherwise Electron app will freeze)
15. Copy the entire output folder into your Electron app folder. `MyApp\windows.devices.geolocation\` etc. and modify the top level package.json file with this dependency as `"windows.devices.geolocation": "file:windows.devices.geolocation"`
16. Check your electron version using `MyApp\node_modules/.bin/electron --version` for me it was 4.0.1
17. Run the following command to rebuild the NodeRT module to work in electron 
    `node-gyp rebuild --target=4.0.1 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell`
18. Now run the `npm install` at the MyApp folder and your NodeRT is ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

To add here, what eventually worked for me, besides having the C++ tools installed, was using the `-rs3` version, rather than just `nodert-win10`:

```
npm install @nodert-win10-rs3/windows.media
```