# Access GPS location of Windows Tab in Electron + React App

Tags: windows, reactjs, npm, gps, electron

I am developing an electron app (with ReactJS based UI) that needs the GPS location of the tablet. The tablet runs Windows 10 and is equipped with GPS hardware. After googling for a couple of hours, I am unable to find any npm plugin for electron that can fetch the GPS location of the tablet.

> Is there a known plugin or API that can accomplish this?

I am also thinking about the Geolocation API in Javascript but currently unable to verify if that works due to the lack of Win 10 tablet with GPS.

> Please share your thoughts or experiences on the best way forward.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am trying to accomplish the very same task and came across the npm module NodeRT (https://github.com/NodeRT/NodeRT) which should do the task (getting GPS coordinates through the windows.devices.geolocation API). But im struggling to get it setup ... here are some solutions (which did not work out for me yet) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157554/nodert-could-not-find-assembly/42161291#42161291 Hope this helps, otherwise there is a workaround where you call powershell which queries the GPS coordinates from windows.devices.geolocation API through nodejs and parse the stdout.